# Get data from List<String> column

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with the following columns:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
dt.Columns.Add("name",typeof(string));  
dt.Columns.Add("Database",typeof(List<String>)); 
dt.Columns.Add("schedule", typeof(String));  
dt.Columns.Add("Path",typeof(List<String>)); 
gridTask.DataSource = dt;
```

When I insert a new row, everything is ok:

```
List<string> database = new List<string>(){"test1","test2","test3"};
List<string> path = new List<string>(){"test1","test2","test3"};
dt.Row.add((new object[] {"Test",database,"Test",path });
gridTask.DataSource = dt;
```

But I want to know how can I get the data from the columns `List<String>`

Comment: dt.Rows[0]["Database"]

Comment: Are you trying to create three rows, with the values in the lists? Because you're only creating one row with lists inside cells.

Comment: I use dt.Rows[x]["column"] to get data, in the String column no problem, but in List<String> Column i can't get data from the list.

Comment: I wanna get each String from the list<String> column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
List<String> str = (List<String>)dt.Rows[x]["column"];
```